# Visualizing the relationships of classes and methods in Python

Tags: python, static-analysis, class-diagram

I am reading the source code of a game written in Python, which involves a lot of methods under many classes tangles together. I want to start with a graph which gives an overview of the whole package. Something like `Class1.methodA` uses `Class2.methodA` and `Class2.methodC`; `Class2.methodC` uses `Class2.methodB`.... And presented in a graph with nodes and arrows so that I can see the dependencies clearly.

I can certainly do that manually level by level, but that will take a lot of time and might mess up when it gets complex.

I've seen a tool called "snakefood" which visualize dependencies. I tried but failed (does not work for Python3? I am not sure why. And therefore also not sure if it is what I am looking for). Any suggestions?

Comment: I haven't tried it but a google search yielded https://github.com/crbunney/snakefood. It says "Python 2.7 or higher. Python-3.x works too." in the readme

Comment: I followed their document but still doesn't work on Python 3.6.9. And I looked at some of their example output and found them really messy when the package is "large". It doesn't reflect any hierarchy or structure at all.

Comment: It may be worth trying to run it using Python 2 on the Python 3 source code. If you don't like the visualisation you could just use it to generate the dependencies using the `sfood`, command then messing around with your own visualisation.